# Database Design in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

I am designing a database for school.

Requirements

- Professors have an SSN, a name, an age, gender, a rank, and a research specialty
- Professors work in exactly one department
- Departments have a department number, a department name, and a main office
- Departments must have one professor (known as the chairman) who runs the department

My current schema for "Professors" and "Departments"

```
CREATE DOMAIN SSN AS CHAR(11) CONSTRAINT validSSN CHECK (VALUE ~* "^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$");

CREATE TABLE Persons (
    person_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ssn SSN NOT NULL CONSTRAINT mustBeDifferent UNIQUE,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    age INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT nonnegativeAge CHECK(age >= 0),
    gender CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT mustBeMaleOrFemale CHECK(gender = "M" OR gender = "F") NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Professors (
    ranking INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT positiveRanking CHECK(ranking > 0),
    research_specialty VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    department_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Departments(department_number)
) INHERITS(Persons);

CREATE TABLE Departments (
    department_number INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    department_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    main_office VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    chairman_id INT REFERENCES Professors(person_id)
);
```

I have a foreign key in the "Professors" table that references the "Departments" table and a foreign key in the "Departments" table that references the "Professors" table.

**Is there any way that I could go about resolving this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems:

- `professors` should not inherit from `persons`, but reference it with a foreign key.

  Otherwise you cannot guarantee uniqueness of the primary key.
- Don't store the `age` in `persons`, but the birthday.

  Otherwise your data will grow invalid pretty quickly.
- If there is no length limit dictated by the application, don't use `varchar(255)`, but use `text`.